# weasyprint html to pdf blank

Tags: python, pdf, weasyprint

I have installed weasyprint on Windows 7 and try to export an html string to pdf. Unfortunately the pdf output remains blank. Only the headings are visible as bookmarks in Acrobat Reader.This is the case for even the simplest html strings such as:

```
html = <h1>test</h1>
HTML(string=html).write_pdf('test.pdf')
```

I run python 2.7 and have installed lxml, cffi, GTK+, I use Acrobat Reader XI. Png output does give the expected result. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try some test html with more than just a heading -- i.e. with something in the body.

Comment: I can not reproduce this, but it sounds like a font embedding bug. Could you upload the output PDF somewhere, and file a bug on github? By the way, I do not usually watch StackOverflow for WeasyPrint question. Writing to WeasyPrint’s mailing list or issue tracker will get more response.

Comment: did you resovle this issue? I face the same error.